# How to use Objective-C __nonnull in a backwards-compatible way?

Tags: xcode, compatibility, nullable, non-nullable

Xcode has recently added `__nonnull`, `__nullable`, etc. attributes. However, they're not supported by older versions of clang and other compilers.

How can I use these attributes in a compatible way?

I hoped something like this would work:

```
#ifndef NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
#define __nonnull 
#endif
```

but it seems that `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` is not a real macro, and it's "not defined" in Xcode7.

And it would make sense for this to work:

```
#if !defined(__is_identifier) || __is_identifier(__nonnull)
#define __nonnull
#define __nullable
#endif
```

but Xcode 6 chokes on that with "token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression" error.

Comment: Use `_has_feature(nullability)` as described in https://gist.github.com/smileyborg/d513754bc1cf41678054

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the question, all good methods seem not to work. The most blunt one does:

```
#if !defined(__clang_major__) || __clang_major__ < 7
#define __nonnull
#define __nullable
#endif
```