# AFNetworking returns error after downgrade Xcode

Tags: xcode, afnetworking

I have started AFNetworking with Xcode 7, but today for some reason I downgraded to Xcode 6.4. Previously, the following code was working. But in Xcode 6.4, it gives me bunch of errors. I could not able to figure out.

```
   NSDictionary *params = @{@"id" : [pDetailData uid]};
    [manager POST:URLString parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
        resultDict=responseObject;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isUserProduct" sender:self];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Product" message:[error localizedDescription]delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];
```

Snapshot of error messages

[image]

**Update:** I have added the following based on the suggestion, then it works

```
#import "ProductDetailViewController.h"

#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
#if !defined(__clang_major__) || __clang_major__ < 7
#define _Nonnull
#define _Nullable
#endif


@implementation ProductDetailViewController
```

**Update 2:** Now I am getting the following error, I am not sure whether or not this one is also related my original question, but this error appeared after I downgraded to Xcode 6.4 from Xcode 7.1

[image]

Comment: Case and underscores matter. `_Nonnull` is not the same as `__nonnull`.

Comment: You are right rmaddy. See my update. Is it right approach, is not it?

Comment: Rmaddy, could u please check my second update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `_Nonnull`, is Xcode7 specific, so Xcode6 can't recognize the block parameters....

Remove the _Nonnull annotation, or [use this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31111715/312312)

Comment: More correctly, `_Nonnull` is a new Objective-C feature supported by a newer version of the compiler. Xcode 6 doesn't use that newer compiler.

Comment: Could you please check the update in my question. I am confused what I am still missing. Even I clean and build the project, still same errors exist.

Comment: @texas Did you try removing the _Nonnull attributes ? Try this first and then we can see if the solution I linked to is working or not

Comment: Makes no sense to me. If you move the `UIAlertView` block outside the block, is it compiling ?